# Use a variable in 'git url' jenkins piplines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So when using a Jenkins pipeline I need to checkout a second git repository in a new folder:

```
dir('platform') {
        println("\n\n\n=== === ===> gitBranch ${gitbranch} ");

        dir('platform') {
            deleteDir()
        }

        git url: 'git@gitlab.platform-automation.git', credentialsId: '1234567890', branch: 'feature/Packer-server-image-builds' // clones repo to subdir
}
```

When I try to use a variable to set the branch the command fails:

```
git url: 'git@gitlab.platform-automation.git', credentialsId: '1234567890', branch: '${gitbranch}'
```

What do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"` instead of `'` to use variables: `"${gitbranch}"`